# flutter program on mac OS

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart, permissions, sandbox

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xr in debug mode...
Updating project for Xcode compatibility.
Upgrading project.pbxproj
Upgrading Runner.xcscheme
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           1135.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Sandbox: rsync(15466) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/blesstembangacha/Downloads/incaresjobs/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework

Error (Xcode): Flutter failed to write to a file at "/Users/blesstembangacha/Downloads/incaresjobs/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/.last_build_id".

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone Xr.

When i run on my simulator i get this error, but if i run a different project i get results.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I see that your project is inside your `Downloads`folder. Try moving it somewhere else to check if it is a permission problem